# How to set a variable inside script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page name index.php. And I have a script variable as follows at the top of the page:

```
<script>
    var search_quarry = "some_test";
</script>
```

At the bottom of the same page I want to add this variable into the `src` attribute of a script tag:

```
<script src=NEED_TO_ADD_HERE></script>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<script src=search_quarry> </script>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: A better approach would be to create a variable *in your server programming language* (probably php). Then it is trivial to inject that *php variable* anywhere you want it in your HTML. You are trying to do a task in your browser programming language (javascript), that it is more sensible to do in your server programming language, before the HTML is sent to the user's browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd need to do with DOM manipulation:

```
var search_query = 'some_test';
s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = search_query;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

or, as an alternative, though I'm not sure if this'd work:

```
<script id="fixme"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var search_query = 'some_test';
    document.getElementById('fixme').src = search_query;
</script>
```

Comment: The second variant doesn't work, since I guess a script tag is not a document element; you get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do this? Seems like a hack to make sever code work without fixing the back end

Option 1 is with document.write

```
<script>
    document.write("<script src='" + search_quarry + "'></scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
```

Option 2 is to use createElement and appendChild

```
<script>
    var scr = document.createElement("script");
    scr.src = search_quarry;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scr);  //or use body with document onready
</script>
```

Comment: BE CAREFUL WHILE COPYING Option 1: Two '+' characters placed after "'></scr" leads problems in the code, so it should be only one '+'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot use a javascript variable inside the declaration tags for javascript. That is the point of the tags: everything inside them is parsed as javascript; everything outside them is not.

Comment: Lol, why is this downvoted. You are 100% correct.. The top answer isn't even a solution to this specific question...

Comment: The first few times I read this, it didn't seem correct to me. I finally realized my confusion came from two factors. 1) "inside the declaration tags" I read as the same as "everything inside of the tags" (the contents). Perhaps "as an attribute in a script tag declaration" would be clearer. 2) IMHO, "outside them" would mean "elsewhere in the file". The "tag declaration" itself is neither "inside itself" nor "outside of itself".

Comment: This is a good literal answer to the question. It would probably be better to provide some leads to solve the problem, as the OP's intentions seem pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do what you want

```
window.onload=function(){
    var script=document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript";
    script.src=search_quarry;
    document.appendChild(script)
}
```

Although you would like to change `window.onload` into something else or just put the code inside at the top level, or if using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).append("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+search_quarry+"'/>");
});
```